# Is it possible to open one infopath from another infopath form browser enabled 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have a form with multiple views and each view is too heavy to run.
So, is it possible to have multiple form, where one can open another (Browser enabled to upload in SharePoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating hyperlink inside one form with this URL

```
https://Sharepoint/sites/myTopSite/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=https://Sharepoint/sites/myTopSite/myLibrary/Forms/template.xsn&Source=https://Sharepoint/sites/myTopSite&DefaultItemOpen=1
```

Comment: will that open the new template ?

Comment: yes it will open another form if you will use multiple forms

Comment: thanks for your answer it actually solved one problem but I came across second one.Now if a user wants to edit and change the next form, he won't be able to as the link always aim to new form. Is there any way to solve that.

Comment: try opening the saved form and check the URL. From there, get the pattern and check the parameters that will direct to that form (ID). The use that in your first form to open that next form using the ID parameter.